# When i try to share sound on my Android App(basically to Whatsapp),"Sharing failed error is the error that i get

Tags: android

```
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("I have sound folder that i can easily reach it on domain link" + sounds.getSound());
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("audio/mp3");
                share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Audio File"));
```

*/
Everytime i try to share a sound on my Android app that i've been working on but i always get an error called"Failed sharing,please try again". Is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide an actual value for the parameter that you are passing to `Uri.parse()`. Nobody is going to know what "sound folder that i can easily reach it on domain link" means.

Comment: It is my path where all my sounds are.It is for http://example..com

Comment: Do you mean that it is an `http` or `https` URL?

Comment: It's a http url .

Answer (score 0):

The value of `EXTRA_STREAM` [is documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) to be a `content` `Uri`, not an `http` or `https` `Uri`. While apps might support other schemes — `file` is often supported — you should not assume that any app will support `http`.

Either eliminate this code, or download your MP3 file (e.g., to `getFilesDir()`) and then use `FileProvider` to create a `content` `Uri` that you can use with `EXTRA_STREAM`.